# Unsecured desktop sharing

Tags: security

Can anyone advise me of the best way to get around mongrel hackers.
I came home to find my mouse pointer merrily moving across the screen, opening disgusting web pages and what looked like trying to run a script file.
I immediately switched the machine off and removed the network cable however when i opened firefox it would just go to porn sites.. logged in as another user and am now running beachbit and clamAV as sudo to clean it out however my browser is still stuffed.. any IDEAS people, I need that desktop connection for my work.
I expect I will have to re-install ubuntu?

Comment: I would suggest install an uncomplicated firewall locally which inturn shuts the VNC/SSH e.t.c when you are connected to internet.

Comment: Will that shut off my access to my sharing? I suppose it is better to use Ubuntu one for my files?

Comment: No It does not shut off your sharing on Ubuntu One, since that uses a different storage protocol. Also with the below answer by Eliah, you will indeed have a much secure and smoother working environment. Please setup the firewall refer to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW , install anti-rootkits like chkroot/rkhunter.

Answer (score 1):

You might be asking the wrong question. You're thinking about what you can do to prevent *future* attacks, but the risks to you from *this* one appear from your description to be *far from over.*

From your description, it seems your system was broken into by an actual person (not just some automated process), who did *whatever they wanted* to your system. They may have installed [rootkits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rootkit) or made any other nasty, subtle changes.

**You have to wipe your disk and reinstall. In this particular situation, it's *especially* impossible to predict all the changes that may have been made to your system.** There's debate about whether or not this is always necessary after malware infection, but here, you really *cannot* predict what has happened because a real person directly controlled your computer. There's no question about it: the first thing to do is wipe your disk and reinstall from trusted media.

If you continue to use this system without wiping the disk and reinstalling, you put your own information security, as well as that of any other users and anyone who relies on you to keep any electronic data in confidence.

If you don't have fully current backups, you should of course *documents* first, preferably by booting from a live CD/DVD/USB (don't create it from a file on this computer) and accessing them that way.

Before wiping and reinstalling:

- Don't log in to any online services from the compromised system. (Or, if you have already, then at least no *more*.)
- Avoid using the system at all. Don't keep it running.

*After* wiping, and during the reinstallation and afterwards:

- Don't use the same password. Your password shouldn't be stored on your computer in cleartext, but (1) it could have been captured by software installed by the intruder (for example, with a keylogger), and (2) your password hashes could have been dumped and might successfully be cracked, especially these days with cheap cloud computing and multi-GPU password crackers.
- Change all your passwords for any online services you've accessed from this computer in the recent past (even somewhat before the attack). And if there's any chance your password for an online service was *stored* in your browser or elsewhere on your computer, make sure to change it *even* if you hadn't logged in to it for a long time before the attack. Passwords stored in web browsers are trivially easy for anyone with control over your system to access.
- If you store credit card or other such data on your computer--especially if it's saved in a web browser or in a client application--or if you've accessed such personal financial information recently through your computer, you should be alert for the possibility of attempts at identity theft. In this case, you should read your credit card and bank statements carefully. Needless to say, as covered by the previous point, you should change any passwords for online banking if you've used the on this computer.

Comment: Thank you.. this doesn't give me comfort however it is a plan of action.

Comment: Honestly speaking i have had RDS open for months..Who knows what has been done to it or when. Worried worried worried!!!!

Comment: @Gwyllym Well, the good news is, it's very unlikely that whatever they did would persist across wiping the disk and reinstalling. "Flattening and rebuilding," as it's sometimes called, is remarkably effective at fixing malicious alterations to a system. ...You mention "RDS." If you're looking for specific information about securing some remote administration service you've *deliberately* installed for your own use, you might want to post a new question with specific details, *or* edit this one with the information. (Right now your question is pretty general, as are comments and my answer.)

Comment: Thank you very much. I think that ubuntu one is a much safer alternative after this experience. Contacted the bank, cancelled credit cards etc, changed online passwords. I guess we all live and learn.